# Memory not beeing freed while indixing using solrj

Tags: java, memory-management, solr, jvm, solrj

We start indexing data from DB using solrj , we retrieve about 1 million record from the DB and then we make some process using java over the record .
But we face some problem with the memory .
When we start the indexing process  the memory start growing to reach 7 G .the problem is that the indexing process finish but the memory dose not decrease its keep allocation for the 7 G.

Comment: Do you mean the memory that the JVM holds or did you have a look into the JVM - with tools like VisualVM (can be found in your JAVA_HOME/bin) - and you can see that the memory is still hold by solr?

Comment: The memory is hold by the server that contain the solr  war and the application that index the data war .also i did not use the VisualVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say that the JVM holds the memory, I think you have the problem that is elaborated in [JVM sending back memory to OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675589/jvm-sending-back-memory-to-os)

To tackle this you will need to do as Michael Borgwardt wrote there:

> If you want the JVM to return memory to the OS more eagerly, you can use the [tuning parameters of the Oracle JVM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html), specifically -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio and -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio

Comment: but this option will work with jdk_JRockit or not ?also i read that is related also with the OS as we use Linux.

Comment: No, these commandline arguments will not do for jrockit. But as far as I read (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13188_01/jrockit/docs142/intro/newftrs.html#1000276) jrockit should free heap out of the box. So I would advise you to check if you have a memory leak in your solrj routine.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the answer to your problem, from the below links:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching

http://www.lucidimagination.com/content/scaling-lucene-and-solr