# Clojure doesn't release memory

Tags: image, clojure, jvm

I'm learning Clojure and I'm wondering why my application is consuming so much
memory and not releasing it once it's done using those data structures.  I
imagine that there is something in Clojure that I don't know about that is
making the application *hold onto* some stuff by mistake.

It's a simple thumbnailing app.  It takes images from a directory, resizes
them and puts them into another directory.  It uses the `javax.imageio` and
`java.awt.image` libraries.

```
(def thumb "path to thumbnails directory")

(defn get-thumb-filename [thumb-dir filename width]
  (str thumb-dir (fs/name filename) "_" width ".jpg"))

(defn get-thumb-filename-100 [filename]
  (get-thumb-filename thumb filename 100))

(defn small-thumbnail [filename]
  (make-thumbnail filename (get-thumb-filename-100 filename) 100))

(defn make-thumbnail [filename new-filename width]
  (let [img (javax.imageio.ImageIO/read (as-file filename))
        imgtype (java.awt.image.BufferedImage/TYPE_INT_ARGB)
        width (min (.getWidth img) width)
        height (* (/ width (.getWidth img)) (.getHeight img))
        simg (java.awt.image.BufferedImage. width height imgtype)
        g (.createGraphics simg)]
    (.drawImage g img 0 0 width height nil)
    (.dispose g)
    (javax.imageio.ImageIO/write simg "png" (as-file new-filename))))


;; `images` is a list of original filenames
;; Kick it off with...
(pmap small-thumbnail images)
```

This code is part of a Noir view, meaning that the application doesn't exit
after the processing of all images is finished.

When I run this code, my computer starts going crazy.  The fan gets loud and
the main java process uses over 1GB of memory.  When all images are processed,
the CPU usage goes down to < 5% but the memory usage stays the same.

How can I make it release all of this memory that it *clearly* doesn't need for
anything?

Thanks!

PS: Please let me know if you need me to fill in any details.

Comment: how are you measuring memory use?  does java free memory back to the os?  that would surprise me (but it might).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324499/java-still-uses-system-memory-after-deallocation-of-objects-and-garbage-collecti

Comment: I'm measuring memory consumption by looking at the process in Activity Monitor. It just sits there, using 1GB of RAM.

Comment: then see the link i posted above.  it could be that clojure has released all the memory, but that the jvm is keeping it to re-use later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JVM manages it's own memory.  Once it acquires memory from the operating system, it usually doesn't give it back.  (Or at least I've never seen Sun's JVM do so, there might be some way to force it to...)

Anyhow, a simple way to see whether or not your program is actually leaking memory using tools that you've probably already got installed is to attach a JConsole to your JVM and just monitor the heap usage.  Looking at Activity Monitor won't tell you anything useful.

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html

Comment: if you look at the link i posted in the question comments it appears that since jdk5 it is possible for it to return memory.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this at the repl, the results of the `pmap` are being stored in `*1` for your later use; that won't happen in production, and you could stop it from happening at the repl with, for example, `(dorun (pmap ...))`.

Comment: No, this isn't at the REPL. It's inside a Noir view. Changing `(println (pmap ...))` to `(dorun (pmap ..))` seems to have no effect. How would production be different? Wouldn't I have to add a `:production` profile for leiningen?